# Define the relation $\mathscr{R}$ on $\Bbb Z$ by $x \mathscr{R} y$ iff $xy >0$. I wish to examine several properties of this relation.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, relations, equivalence-relations

Considering on $\mathbb{Z}$ the following relation:

$$\mathscr{R} = \left \{ (x,z) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \quad \mbox{ such that } \quad xz > 0  \right \}$$

i.e. $\forall x,z \in \mathbb{Z}, x \mathscr{R} z \iff \mbox{ the product } \, \, x \cdot z > 0 $

Check if the relation $\mathscr{R}$ is:

i) reflexive;
ii) symmetrical;
iii) transitive;
iv) anti-symmetrical;
v) of order;
vi) of equivalence.

What I have done is the following:
i) is it a reflexive relation?
$\forall x,x \in \mathbb{Z}, \quad x \mathscr{R} x \iff x\cdot x = x^2 > 0 $
since a square is always $> 0$ the relation is reflexive.

ii) is it a symmetrical relation?
$\forall x,z \in \mathbb{Z}, \quad x \mathscr{R} z \iff x \cdot z > 0$ by hypothesis,
since the operation of multiplication is commutative on $\mathbb{Z}$ the following is true:
$\forall x,z \in \mathbb{Z}, \quad z \mathscr{R} x \iff z \cdot x > 0$
hence, the relation is symmetrical.

iii) is it a transitive relation?
$\forall x,z \in \mathbb{Z}, \quad x \mathscr{R}z \iff x \cdot z > 0$ by hypothesys,
if we take another ordered pair
$\forall z,m \in \mathbb{Z}, \quad z \mathscr{R} m \iff z \cdot m > 0$
hence,
if $x \mathscr{R}z, \quad z \mathscr{R} m \Rightarrow x \cdot m > 0$
i.e. if $x \cdot z > 0, \quad z \cdot m > 0 \Rightarrow x \cdot m > 0$
so the relation is transitive.

iv) is it a anti-symmetrical relation?
No. Because it is not true that $z \mathscr{R}x \iff x=z$, as we have seen in the symmetrical relation.

v) is it a order relation?
No. Because it is not anti-symmetrical.

vi) is it a equivalence relation?
Yes, because it is reflexive, symmetrical and transitive.

What do you think about it?
Please, can you give me any suggestions? Many thanks!

Comment: (i) is wrong because $z=0$ does not satisfy $z\cdot z>0$.

Comment: ii) is phrased strangely.  The third line as it is written does not follow from the fact that multiplication is commutative but rather follows directly from the definition of the relation.  What you mean to write is $x\mathcal{R}z\iff x\cdot z>0\iff z\cdot x>0\iff z\mathcal{R}x$

Comment: @amwhy yes... my argument does.  His however as it is originally written seems incoherent and doesn't appear to link $x\mathcal{R} z$ to $z\mathcal{R} x$ but instead goes off on a tangent and just restates the original definition of the relation with different labels.  He never stated that $x\mathcal{R} z$ implies or doesn't imply $z\mathcal{R} x$.  What he wrote is equivalent to $x\mathcal{R} z \implies (z\mathcal{R} x\iff z\cdot x>0)$ which is not the same thing as $x\mathcal{R} z \implies z\mathcal{R} x$.

Comment: @JMoravits if you answer containing your above argumentation, I will assign as best answer.

Answer (score 1):

$
\newcommand{\RR}{\mathscr{R}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
$
Note, intuitively, what we have. This relation $\RR$ on $\Z$ essentially means $x \RR y$ if and only if $x,y$ have the same sign and are nonzero. (Same sign ensures nonnegative, nonzero ensures positive.) Hopefully this makes the intuition clearer.

Onto the errors with your approach:

- You were wrong on reflexivity. Yes, $x^2 > 0$ for any $x \in \Z$, but only if $x \ne 0$.
- Your justification for transitivity is unclear, in my opinion.
- Your justification for antisymmetry seems to amount to "it's symmetrical and thus not antisymmetrical." The properties are not necessarily opposed; a relation can be both, or neither. You're right in that this relation is not antisymmetrical, though, but even so. (In particular, a relation on $A$ of the form $\{(x,x) \mid x \in X\}$ for some $X \subseteq A$ is both antisymmetric and symmetric.)

Onto the overall right ideas:

- **Reflexivity:** This does not hold, because $(0,0) \not \in \RR$. This is because $0 \cdot 0 = 0 \not > 0$.
- **Symmetry:** This does hold under commutativity of integer multiplication. Assume $(x,z) \in \RR$. Then $xz > 0$. But then $xz = zx > 0$. Thus, $(z,x) \in \RR$ on the premise $(x,z) \in \RR$.
- **Transitivity:** This does hold. It's easiest to refer back to the intuitive idea: $(a,b) \in \RR$ if and only if $a,b$ are nonzero and share the same sign. Suppose $(a,b),(b,c) \in \RR$. Then $a,b$ share the same sign, and are nonzero; likewise, the same is true of $b,c$. Thus, $a,b,c$ are nonzero and have the same sign. Thus, $a,c$ have the same sign and are nonzero, and thus $(a,c) \in \RR$.
  Of course, this can be verified algebraically too. Since $(a,b),(b,c) \in \RR$, then $ab>0$ and $bc>0$. Multiply the inequalities and you have $ab^2c > 0$. Since $b \ne 0$ (otherwise neither inequality would hold) and $b^2 >0$ as a result, we may divide both sides by $b^2$ and see $ac > 0$. Thus, $(a,c) \in \RR$.
- **Antisymmetry:** Anti-symmetry requires that, when $(a,b) \in \RR$ and $(b,a) \in \RR$, that $a=b$. However, commutativity of multiplication allows them to be distinct. More specifically: $(1,2),(2,1) \in \RR$ since $1 \cdot 2 = 2 = 2 \cdot 1 > 0$, but obviously $1 \ne 2$.
- **Order:** An order relation requires antisymmetry, so we don't have this.
- **Equivalence:** Since we don't have reflexivity, we don't have equivalence.

Answer (score -3):

$x\cdot x\geq0$  (is always greater than zero), it is reflexive.

$x\cdot z\geq0,\,z\cdot x>0$, it is symmetry

$x\cdot z>0,\,z\cdot y>0,\,x\cdot y>0,\,x\cdot z\geq0$ therfore fore $x\cdot z=x\cdot y$ it is transitivity

Comment: well $0\cdot 0\not>0$.